# vim fails to match symbols in php properly

Tags: php, vim, matching

```
<?php
    $foo->bar();
?>
```

If you press % while the cursor is on the first '<' the cursor moves to the next '>' instead of the one in the last line.

Any chance to fix this?

edit:

my vim version:

```
$ vim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.3 (2010 Aug 15, compiled Mar 24 2011 07:09:45)
```

i also have matchit.vim installed for the case that it matters.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the matchit plugin.  That allows smarter matching of tokens based on the given filetype being edited.  `:help matchit-install` will tell you how you can setup matchit to be sourced on startup so it's available when you're editing.

Once it's setup, when you edit a PHP file, a map will be created for `%` that runs matchit's functionality.  It also defines various buffer-local variables (such as `b:match_words`) which can be tailored to determine how `%` behaves -- recognized tokens, how they're related to each other, etc.